# If $f$ is holomorphic in $B(0,1)$ and $|f|>2$ on the boundary, then its range contains $B(0,2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f\in Hol\overline{\big(B(0,1)\big)}$ and assume $f(0)=1$ and $\forall z: |z|=1\Rightarrow|f(z)|>2$. Prove that $B(0,2)\subset f\big(B(0,1)\big)$ using the argument principle.

I thought using $g(z)=z+1$ means $|f(z)|>2=1+|z|\ge|1+z|$ and $B(0,2)\subset g(B(0,1))$ but that seems too easy. How can I prove that in other ways?

Comment: You mean "$\forall z : \lvert z\rvert = 1 \Rightarrow \lvert f(z)\rvert > 2$", don't you?

Comment: yes. my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument principle says that for all $w$ such that $f(z)\neq w$ for all $\lvert z\rvert = 1$,

$$N(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-w}\,dz$$

is the number of times $f$ attains the value $w$ in the open unit disk (counting multiplicities).

The assumption $f(0) = 1$ means $N(1) > 0$. The desired conclusion is $\lvert w\rvert < 2 \implies N(w) > 0$.

That follows from

1. the continuity of $N$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(\{z:\lvert z\rvert = 1\})$, and
2. the fact that $N$ is integer-valued.

Together, these two properties imply that $N$ is locally constant, and since the disk $\{ w : \lvert w\rvert\}$ is connected and contained in $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(\{z:\lvert z\rvert = 1\})$, $N$ is constant on that disk. Hence $N(w) = N(1) > 0$ for all $\lvert w\rvert < 2$.

Comment: Im not sure I understood why $N(\omega)>0$. and what do you mean by $N(1)$? the zeros of constant function 1?

Comment: No. $N(w)$ is the number of times $f$ attains the value $w$ in the open unit disk. $N(1) > 0$ means that $f$ attains the value $1$ at least once (by assumption $f(0) = 1$, so that gives $N(1) > 0$). What you have to show is that $N(w) > 0$ for all $w$ with $\lvert w\rvert < 2$, that is, each such $w$ is attained as a value by $f$ in the open unit disk.

Comment: so_
$$|\omega|<2⇒N(\omega)>\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f^\prime(z)dz}{f(z)−2}$$ which is analytic since $|f(z)|>2=0$ by cauchy theorem but that's all?

Comment: No, you don't have that inequality (in fact, under the assumptions, it is an equality). Which properties of the function $w\mapsto N(w)$ guarantee that it is constant on the disk $\{w : \lvert w\rvert < 2\}$?

Comment: The only option I can think of is that $\omega\mapsto N(\omega)$ is bounded (maybe by $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}f^\prime(z)dz$.I am again wrong?

Comment: Look at the definition of $N(w)$. Can you read off some continuity or differentiability properties from that? Look at the description of $N(w)$. What kind of values can the function take at all?

Comment: $N(\omega)$ can get only natural values or 0. $|z|=1\Rightarrow f(z)>2$ so f sends $C_1=\{z:|z|<1\}$ "out of it" so $0<N(1)=N(\omega)$ for all $|\omega|<2$?

Comment: Yes, $N(w)$ can only take integer values (non-negative, for this $f$, but that doesn't matter here). I'm not sure how to interpret your second sentence, but the crux is that $N$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(\{z : \lvert z\rvert = 1\})$. Continuous and integer-valued means it is constant on every connected set in its domain. $\{ w : \lvert w\rvert < 2\}$ is a connected set in its domain.

Comment: Why if $f$ is constant and integer-valued on connected domain it's constant?

Comment: The continuity means that (fix a $w_0$) for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert w-w_0\rvert < \delta \implies \lvert N(w) - N(w_0)\rvert < \varepsilon$. Picking an $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, the integer-valuedness then gives you $N(w) = N(w_0)$ for $\lvert w-w_0\rvert < \delta$. So each fibre of $N$ is open, and, since its complement is a union of fibres, hence open, also closed. In a connected space, the only open and closed sets are $\varnothing$ and the whole space, so a connected set must be contained in one fibre of $N$.

Comment: I wouldn't thought about that idea. thanks.

Comment: The following is essentially the same, but relies on a bit less point-set knowledge. If $f : X \to Y$ is continuous and $Y$ is discrete, then $f$ is locally constant, since inverse images of singletons are open. Now $N : B(0,2) \to \mathbb{Z}$, so $N$ is locally constant. So for each $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $N^{-1}(z)$ is open, and $B(0,2) = N^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}) = \bigcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} N^{-1}(z)$. If more than one of these is nonempty, then we have written $B(0,2)$ as a disjoint union of more than one nonempty open set, which would imply it is disconnected, which is not true.